# Multiple select not inserting selected options to database

Tags: php, mysql

This is PHP.

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';

if (isset($_POST['add'])) {
    $id = 'NULL';
    $Branch = $_POST['Branch'];
    $check = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM staff WHERE id='$id'");
    if (0 == mysqli_num_rows($check)) {
        if (1 == 1) {
            $insert = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO staff(Branch) VALUES('$Branch')") or die(mysqli_error($connect));
            if ($insert) {
                echo '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>Data Successfully Saved.</div>';
            } else {
                echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>OOps, Data Failed to Save!</div>';
            }
        } else {
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>Not the same password!</div>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>ID already exists!</div>';
    }
}
?>
```

This is my mysql column.

```
Branch  text    utf8_general_ci     No  None
```

This is select element from my form.

```
<form action="" method="post">
     <select class="selectpicker form-control" multiple data-live-search="true" name="Branch" required="true">
        <option selected>example 1</option>
        <option value="example 2">example 2</option>
        <option value="example 3">example 3</option>
        <option value="example 4">example 4</option>
      </select>
</form>
```

My problem is next, 
if i choose one option its indexing database without any problem.
if i choose more then one option, last selected option is indexing.
So what i want is if i select 2 option for example "example 1, example 2" this both should be index as text in my mysql.

P.S. I know that i am noob and non English speaker but please support me.

Comment: Could you please add some PHP code? And what exactly do you want to insert into the column 'Branch'? A text like "example 1, example 2"?

Comment: How are you connecting to the database?

Comment: I add my php code

Comment: I don't understand the SELECT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, change attribute name like this `name="Branch[]"`

next, use `foreach` loop and retrieve the value one by one

```
$branches = $_POST['Branch']; //get values in array

$insert_string = ''; //we need to concat array values into this empty variable
```

use `foreach` loop

```
foreach($branches as $branch){
   $insert_string .= $branch . ", "; //set values with comma separater
}

//insert
$insert = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO staff(Branch) VALUES('$insert_string')") or 
             die (mysqli_error($connect));
```

Comment: He/She doesn't want to insert multiple records, but instead insert one record with a concatenated string.

Comment: You are Genius, Thank you my mate

Comment: Instead of using a foreach loop to concatenate a string, you could use `implode()`, which doesn't add an extra comma to the end. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give it an array-style name, `name="Branch[]"`. Then `$_POST['Branch']` will be an array containing all the selected values, and you can insert all the values from it in a loop.

```
if (isset($_POST['Branch'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['Branch'] as $branch) {
        // insert $branch into the database
    }
}
```

If you want to insert a comma-delimited string you can use `implode`:

```
$branches = implode(',', $_POST['Branch']);
```

But it's geneally poor database design to put multiple items in a single column. See [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Also, in the HTML, `required="true"` should be either `required` or `required="required"`. Boolean attributes don't use `true/false` values; they either have no value, the value is the same as the attribute name, or they're omitted.

Comment: I try this one but nothing changed, its indexing text "Array"

Comment: I mean exactly "Array" text is indexing in db.

Comment: That means you're not looping over the array. If you try to use an array as a string, it becomes the word `Array`.

Comment: I thought it would be clear when I said "you can insert all the values from it in a loop", but I've added example code to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the `<select>` element should be `Branch[]`. In your PHP script you'll need to get the value with `$branches = implode(',', $_POST['Branch']);` before inserting `$branches` into the database.